# Animate ScaleX and ScaleY over time with tween not working in CocosSharp

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xamarin.ios, cocossharp

I am trying to animate the ScaleX and ScaleY properties of my Sprite using the following code. Nothing is happening though. I am used to using UIViews and the UIView.Animate method which allows me to set my end result and a duration. Is something like this possible with cocos?

```
        baloon.RunAction(new CCActionTween(.009f, "ScaleX", baloon.ScaleX,  (float)(w / baloon.ContentSize.Width)));
        baloon.RunAction(new CCActionTween(.009f, "ScaleY", baloon.ScaleY,  (float)(h / baloon.ContentSize.Height)));
```